# PHPExcel not generating sheet with Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, phpexcel

I am using [PHPExcel](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) for creating excel sheets but I am facing issue with Ajax. In Ajax I am not able to generate sheet when Ajax is succeeded. In my current code without Ajax implantation sheet is generating and every time asking to save as option window.

**Code without Ajax (Working):**

```
/** Error reporting */
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

define('EOL',(PHP_SAPI == 'cli') ? PHP_EOL : '<br />');

/** Include PHPExcel */
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../Classes/PHPExcel.php';

// Create new PHPExcel object
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

// Create new PHPExcel object
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

// Create a first sheet, representing sales data
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', 'Something');

// Rename sheet
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Name of Sheet 1');

// Create a new worksheet, after the default sheet
$objPHPExcel->createSheet();

// Add some data to the second sheet, resembling some different data types
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(1);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', 'More data');

// Rename 2nd sheet
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Second sheet');

// Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);


header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="name_of_file_'.date('Y/m/d H:i:s').'.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

**Code with Ajax (Not Working):**

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="create">Create</a>
```

jQuery Ajax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#create').click(function() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost/testing/PHPExcel_1.8.0_doc/Examples/create.php",
            data: "",
            success: function (html) {

            }
        });     

    });
</script>
```

Create.php

```
<?php
    /** Error reporting */
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);

    define('EOL',(PHP_SAPI == 'cli') ? PHP_EOL : '<br />');

    /** Include PHPExcel */
    require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../Classes/PHPExcel.php';

    // Create new PHPExcel object
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

    // Create a first sheet, representing sales data
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', 'Something');

    // Rename sheet
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Name of Sheet 1');

    // Create a new worksheet, after the default sheet
    $objPHPExcel->createSheet();

    // Add some data to the second sheet, resembling some different data types
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(1);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', 'More data');

    // Rename 2nd sheet
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Second sheet');

    // Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel5)
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="name_of_file_'.date('Y/m/d H:i:s').'.xlsx"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
?>
```

Getting this response:

[image]

Any Idea? Why sheet is not generating and why save as window is not opening.

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot download a file like that using an Ajax call. Google "ajax download file" to see a number of alternate solutions (many right here on SO of course)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ajax to generate file, you need to follow these steps:

1. Send request to server/PHP to generate the file. Save that file & send file name in response.
2. Upon receiving filename in success callback, redirect your browser to any php file which shows the actual geneared file (with headers)i.e. `window.location.href='downloadFile.php?filename=abcd.pdf'`

Comment: Or a bit easier (since it doesn't require saving a file on the server) - append a form element to your HTML document, set its method to POST and its action to your php file, and submit it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#create').click(function() {

        $.ajax({
            url: "",
            beforeSend: function() {
            location.href = "http://localhost/testing/PHPExcel_1.8.0_doc/Examples/create.php";
            },
            success: function (html) {

            }
        });     

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

PHP Code --> Return Array

```
        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel'); 
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$filename.'"'); 
        header('Cache-Control: max-age=0'); 


        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');  

        $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5($objPHPExcel);

        $objWriter->save("php://output");
        $xlsData = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();

        $objPHPExcel->disconnectWorksheets();
        unset($objPHPExcel);


        $response =  array(
            'status' => true,
            'file' => "data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,".base64_encode($xlsData),
            'log' => $log_mensaje
        );
```

JQUERY CODE

function crear_reporte_turno(id){

```
  var $mensaje = "¿Está seguro de Crear el Reporte del Turno?";
  var $form = $('<div></div>');
  $form.append('<p>'+$mensaje+'</p>');

  BootstrapDialog.show({
    title: 'Consulta',
    //type: BootstrapDialog.TYPE_DANGER,
    size: BootstrapDialog.SIZE_SMALL,
    message: $form,
    autospin: true,
    buttons: [{
        label: 'Continuar',
        cssClass: 'btn-primary',
        autospin: true,
        action: function(dialogRef){

            dialogRef.enableButtons(false);
            dialogRef.setClosable(false);

            url = '<?php echo $url_ruta_controlador . 'crear_reporte_turno/'; ?>' + id;

            $.post(url,{'id_turno' : id}, function(respuesta){

                dialogRef.close();

                var titulo = "Reporte Turno";
                var mensaje = "";
                var tipo_mensaje = "";
                var $form = $('<div></div>');

                if(respuesta.status){
                    mensaje = "Se ha creado el reporte del turno correctamente.";
                    tipo_mensaje = BootstrapDialog.TYPE_SUCCESS;

                    var $a = $("<a>");
                    $a.attr("href",respuesta.file);

                    $form.append('<p>'+mensaje+'</p>');                 
                    $form.append($a);   

                    var nombre_archivo = "reporte_turno_" + id + ".xls";

                    $a.attr("download",nombre_archivo);
                    $a[0].click();
                    $a.remove();

                    console.log(respuesta.log);


                } else {
                    mensaje = "Se ha producido un error al crear el reporte del turno.";
                    tipo_mensaje = BootstrapDialog.TYPE_DANGER;

                    $form.append('<p>'+mensaje+'</p>'); 
                }

                BootstrapDialog.show({
                    title: titulo,
                    type: tipo_mensaje,
                    message: $form,
                    buttons: [{
                        label: 'Cerrar',
                        action: function(dialogRef){
                            dialogRef.close();
                        }
                    }]
                });

               },'json').fail(function(){

                dialogRef.close();

                var titulo = "Reporte Turno";
                var mensaje = "";
                var tipo_mensaje = "";
                var $form = $('<div></div>');

                mensaje = "Se ha producido un error al crear el reporte del turno.";
                tipo_mensaje = BootstrapDialog.TYPE_DANGER;
                $form.append('<p>'+mensaje+'</p>'); 

                BootstrapDialog.show({
                    title: titulo,
                    type: tipo_mensaje,
                    message: $form,
                    buttons: [{
                        label: 'Cerrar',
                        action: function(dialogRef){
                            dialogRef.close();
                        }
                    }]
                });

              });
            return; 
            }
        },
        {
          label: 'Cancelar',
          action: function(dialogRef){
          dialogRef.close();

        }
      }]      
    }); 
}
```